# Симпатичные всплывающие подсказки на карте

Tags: html, css

Как сделать симпатичные всплывающие подсказки к элементам в навигационной карте?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googl eapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-fckeditor-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.MetaData.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.gi thub.com/kemayo/maphilight/dd84221dec229fa5525760a1c791eb9e08f20dd3/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function() {$("img[usemap]").maphilight();});</script>
<!-- Конец кода для вставки в Ваш тег head -->


    <img alt="z_30e1dd84.jpg" src="http://cs5826.vk.com/u51851451/147177393/z_30e1dd84.jpg" usemap="#myMap" width="600" height="900" />
        <map name="myMap" id="myMap">
            <area shape="poly" coords="1,345,140,348,148,181,2,175" alt="Картины. Мы используем копии работ известных художников. Это оптимальный выбор." class="{fill:false,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'000000',strokeOpacity:0.3,strokeWidth:7}" target="_self" title="Картины. Мы используем копии работ известных художников. Это оптимальный выбор."/>
            <area shape="poly" coords="172,268,174,176,249,179,246,270" alt="Картины. Мы используем копии работ известных художников. Это оптимальный выбор." class="{fill:false,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'000000',strokeOpacity:0.3,strokeWidth:7}" target="_self" title="Картины. Мы используем копии работ известных художников. Это оптимальный выбор."/>
            <area shape="poly" coords="294,311,298,190,394,192,393,311" alt="Картины. Мы используем копии работ известных художников. Это оптимальный выбор." class="{fill:false,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'000000',strokeOpacity:0.3,strokeWidth:7}" target="_self" title="Картины. Мы используем копии работ известных художников. Это оптимальный выбор."/>
            <area shape="poly" coords="314,403,315,346,373,347,371,404" alt="Картины. Мы используем копии работ известных художников. Это оптимальный выбор." class="{fill:false,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'000000',strokeOpacity:0.3,strokeWidth:7}" target="_self" title="Картины. Мы используем копии работ известных художников. Это оптимальный выбор."/>
            <area shape="poly" coords="249,584,260,564,273,538,276,530,299,481,308,484,324,492,380,495,355,586,338,592,293,587,276,581" alt="Текстиль. Текстиль играет большую роль в оформлении интерьера" class="{fill:false,fillColor:'fff100',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'000000',strokeOpacity:0.3,strokeWidth:7}" target="_self" title="Текстиль. Текстиль играет большую роль в оформлении интерьера"/>
        </map>
```

Для примера можно навести курсором на картины. [Демо на JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azc1dqk2/).

Comment: @Melekhin, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Попробуйте https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 1):

Вы имеете ввиду некий контейнер, например "div", который должен всплывать при наведении на элемент DOM-модели. И исчезать при потери фокуса. Так?

Comment: Создайте файл с расширением .html и вставьте туда вышеуказанный код. Потом откройте файл в окне браузера. На экране появится фотка, наведите курсором на картину (любую) - всплывет желтый прямоугольник с текстовой подсказкой. А вопрос в том, как заменить этот желтый прямоугольник на что-то более симпатичное, сохраняя функционал. 
Простите, не совсем понимаю пока что терминологию.